# jQuery Get Elements Color?

Tags: jquery, css, dom, colors

I have the follow HTML

```
<div>This is some <span>special <a href="#">text</a></span> and it's super</div>
```

And CSS

```
span {color:#333;}
a {color:#777;}
a:hover {color:#AAA;}
```

I am wondering what I can use to setup a function that I can extract the color of the <a> and <a>:hover elements?

Thanks

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use the [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method on the element you want to retrieve.

In your example:

```
var theColorIs = $('a').css("color");
```

Which will return the color in RGB.

Comment: nps. dont take my example literally though - my example would actually return a collection of 'a' elements. just modify it to your use.

Comment: hey just wondering - how would I do this for multiple elements ? i.e.var theColorIs = $('a').css("color", "font-size"); as that doesn't seem to work ?

Comment: Check the .css link. The second parameter is what to set the attribute to - in that case you cant set the "color" attribute to the value of "font-size".

Use the "each" function (like described by Josiah below) to iterate over multiple elements.

Answer (score 1):

To get the color CSS attribute of all the  elements you can use JQuery's css() function:

```
$('a').each(function(index) {
               alert( $(this).css('color') );
             });​​​​
```

This will iterate through all the anchor elements on the page and tell you the CSS color attribute thereof.

Comment: hey just wondering - how would I do this for multiple elements ? i.e.var theColorIs = $('a').css("color", "font-size"); as that doesn't seem to work ?

Comment: If you pass a second argument to css() it will set the css attribute specified. For example, to change the color to green you could say:

$('a').css('color','green')

If you want to access multiple CSS properties of an element, you'll have to make the call to css() multiple times:

$('a').css('color);
$('a').css('font-size');

For more info, read the documentation posted in the other answer :)